# How to observe multiple observable threads

Tags: java, multithreading, observer-pattern, observable

I'm trying to create a program in java where threads are observable objects and a window is the observer. What I don't understand is how do I distinguish the several threads, which all do the same thing, from each other on the update method so that I could update their position individually on the window.

Comment: Instead of making them all the same, you can associate a name with each thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Stated in comment by @PeterLawrey you can use the name argument from the [Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#Thread%28java.lang.String%29) object to set an unique name and then query your Threads and find which one is doing what. The constructor is as follows:

```
public Thread(String name)
    Allocates a new Thread object. This constructor has the same effect as Thread (null, null, name).
Parameters:
    name - the name of the new thread
```

But, for accessing the Threads more easily after it's executing, and to track I recommend the use of [ThreadGroup](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadGroup.html) object. From the api docs:

> A thread group represents a set of threads. In addition, a thread group can also include other thread groups. The thread groups form a tree in which every thread group except the initial thread group has a parent.

Therefore, you can use the method [public int enumerate(Thread[] list,
            boolean recurse)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadGroup.html#enumerate%28java.lang.Thread%5b%5d%29)

Which

> Copies into the specified array every active thread in this thread group. If recurse is true, this method recursively enumerates all subgroups of this thread group and references to every active thread in these subgroups are also included. If the array is too short to hold all the threads, the extra threads are silently ignored.

And `getName()` of all threads in the group. I hope it helped. Cheers

Comment: +1 I would suggest you use a Runnable and give it a name field.

Comment: @PeterLawrey:Aren't `ThreadGroups` obsolete for some time now?

Comment: @Cratylus AFAIk ThreadGroups are only useful for application servers. I don't use them.

Comment: I understand. But later in the update(Observable arg0, Object arg1), how can I identify the thread that is uptading? Using a getName()?

Comment: It's like the Vector class. It's just recommended to use ArrayLists now, but there are cases when you need to use Vector and there are cases that you still need to use ThreadGroups. I think this is an example

Comment: What are you using those fields for? Can you add the name?

Comment: @BrunoVieira I use ExecutorServices which I submit named Runnable.  Each Runnable has its own status or Observable or queue of information.

Comment: @PeterLawrey was that a question to me?

Comment: You can use the `getState()` which returns a [Thread.State](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.State.html) and check if a Thread is RUNNING for example. And there is the `holdLock(Object obj)` method too. I recommend you to read the documentation about the [Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#Thread(java.lang.String)) Object

Comment: @PeterLawrey The ExecutorService is the "new" alternative. I think I'm kind of oldschool here since I started with java 1.4 ;)

Comment: @BrunoVieira Java 5.0 which included ExecutorService has been EOL for 3 years. BTW I started with Java 1.2 but I think its worth using the keeping up to date. ;)

Comment: Fair enough @PeterLawrey :). ThreadGroup was the first "solution" that appeared in mind.

Comment: @BrunoVieira I'm kind of a beginner in java, I'm not sure I understand well how ThreadGroup would work. I think I'm having trouble on the observer part, in the update method, I'm not understanding well how this method could identify a random number of diferent threads and update them

Comment: As I said in my answer: `A thread group represents a set of threads`. And as such you can use this object to keep track of your Threads. There are other ways to keep track (and manipulate them) like using `ExecutorService` as stated by @PeterLawrey, or even simply creating an `ArrayList<Thread>` (Which is not a good Idea btw). After that, you can loop through your Thread objects and "ask" them about their names and/or Thread.State

Answer (score 0):

If name is not enough, you could consider using a `ThreadStatic` to store other info about each thread:

```
class ThreadPosition {
   [ThreadStatic]
   private static int x;

   /**
   * Only call from thread.
   **/
   public static int getX()
   {
     return x;
   }
}
```